# Hortonworks Sandbox fails to start after Kerberizing the cluster

Tags: kerberos, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

We are using HDP 2.3 Sandbox on VMware player and it was working as expected before. Two days back I kerberized the cluster with a new MIT KDC (installed and started in the same sandbox.) I could issue the TGTs and things were working as expected.

Today I am trying to start the sandbox and boom! It does not start. Constantly I see the following retried messages. (KDC and kadmin servers I've started and the root/admin user has a valid TGT -verified in the klist)

```
15/10/23 12:17:27 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: sandbox.hortonworks.com/192.168.77.137:8020. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryPolicy[MultipleLinearRandomRetry[6x10000ms, 10x60000ms], TryOnceThenFail]
15/10/23 12:17:36 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: sandbox.hortonworks.com/192.168.77.137:8020. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryPolicy[MultipleLinearRandomRetry[6x10000ms, 10x60000ms], TryOnceThenFail]
15/10/23 12:17:45 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: sandbox.hortonworks.com/192.168.77.137:8020. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryPolicy[MultipleLinearRandomRetry[6x10000ms, 10x60000ms], TryOnceThenFail]
15/10/23 12:18:00 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: sandbox.hortonworks.com/192.168.77.137:8020. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryPolicy[MultipleLinearRandomRetry[6x10000ms, 10x60000ms], TryOnceThenFail]
15/10/23 12:18:07 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: sandbox.hortonworks.com/192.168.77.137:8020. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryPolicy[MultipleLinearRandomRetry[6x10000ms, 10x60000ms], TryOnceThenFail]
```

Answer (score 0):

**192.168.77.137:8020** is a namenode address, and looks like namenode is not started. Check that IP, probably it may have changed, that's why.

Comment: Yes 8020 is NN address. NN does not start after kerberizing. No IP is not changed.

Comment: If so, can you post message from NN start, which is located in Background Operations popup?

Comment: Melhior, thanks for getting back. I did not understand what you are asking for. Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: Follow steps on images: http://i.imgur.com/Zv7n0wt.png http://i.imgur.com/OdzubS1.png http://i.imgur.com/qRUhrVK.png http://i.imgur.com/Z4XPiaS.png